# Rewrite specific sub domain to SSL based?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I use apache 2 on Debian 7.

I have an online tool installed at let's say:

```
tool.myurl.net
```

I do have a wildcard SSL certificate for:

```
*.myurl.net
```

I also configured the `virtualhost` in Apache to listen to `tool.anotherurl.com` using `ServerAlias`.

But I do not have a valid SSL certificate for that URL.

So I need a rewrite rule that redirect `http://tool.myurl.net` to `httpS://tool.myurl.net` BUT NOT when people visit `http://tool.anotherurl.com`.

Is this possible?

Comment: Clarify your question please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you want to redirect to HTTPS only the sub domain `tool.myurl.net` so this rule should do it:

```
RewriteEngine On
# if HTTPS is not being used we force it to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
# because we want to force it for this domain only
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^tool\.myurl\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```